# Responsive image with JavaScript image fade

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the images inside a `div` responsive while JavaScript code that fades the images is running.

HTML:

```
<div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
    <img class="rotating-item" src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-284a.jpg" />
    <img class="rotating-item" src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-263a.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rotating-item-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 19%;
}
.rotating-item {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function () { //start after HTML, images have loaded 

    var InfiniteRotator = {
        init: function () {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 3000;

            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2500;

            //count number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

            //set current item
            var currentItem = 0;

            //show first item
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                    currentItem = 0;
                } else {
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };
    InfiniteRotator.init();
});
```

I tried using `width:100% height:auto;` but the js didnt work well.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle out of it? I can't reproduce the issue.
Also it would be good if you show an example of the behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cL9r6on8/

Comment: How can i change the potision of the div now. I change the top but nothing happens.

Comment: Your wrapper needs a width then http://jsfiddle.net/cL9r6on8/1/